# Bokeh Map Not Showing in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm struggling to get a Bokeh map. The cell runs but does not show anything. It takes about `50s`. I can get a blank map to display, but nothing I have tried has worked.

Jupyter version 6.4.12 run through Anaconda 2.3.2

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON, get_provider
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar, NumeralTickFormatter
from bokeh.palettes import PRGn, RdYlGn
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap, factor_cmap
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.resources import INLINE

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

output_notebook(INLINE)
```

I have Lat & Lon coordinates in my dataset, which I discovered I need to convert to mercator coordinates.

```py
# Define function to switch from lat/long to mercator coordinates
def x_coord(x, y):
    
    lat = x
    lon = y
    
    r_major = 6378137.000
    x = r_major * np.radians(lon)
    scale = x/lon
    y = 180.0/np.pi * np.log(np.tan(np.pi/4.0 + lat * (np.pi/180.0)/2.0)) * scale
    return (x, y)

# Define coord as tuple (lat,long)
df['coordinates'] = list(zip(df['LATITUDE'], df['LONGITUDE']))

# Obtain list of mercator coordinates
mercators = [x_coord(x, y) for x, y in df['coordinates'] ]

# Create mercator column in our df
df['mercator'] = mercators

# Split that column out into two separate columns - mercator_x and mercator_y
df[['mercator_x', 'mercator_y']] = df['mercator'].apply(pd.Series)
```

From there, this is my code cell for the plot:

```
tile = get_provider('CARTODBPOSITRON')
source = ColumnDataSource(data = df)

palette = PRGn[11]

color_mapper = linear_cmap(field_name = 'FIRE_SIZE', palette = palette,
                          low=df['FIRE_SIZE'].min(), high = df['FIRE_SIZE'].max())

tooltips = [('Fire Year', '@FIRE_YEAR'),('State','@STATE')]

p = figure(title = 'Fire Locations',
           x_axis_type = 'mercator',
           y_axis_type = 'mercator',
           x_axis_label = 'Longitude',
           y_axis_label = 'Latitude',
          tooltips = tooltips)

p.add_tile(tile)

p.circle(x = 'mercator_x',
         y = 'mercator_y',
         color = color_mapper,
         size = 10,
         fill_alpha = 0.7,
         source = source)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper = color_mapper['transform'],
                    formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='0.0[0000]'),
           `your text`         label_standoff = 13, width = 8, location = (0,0))

p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

show(p)
```

The cell runs, but nothing shows. There are no errors. I confirmed that I can get a plot to display using this code:

```
#Test

tile = get_provider('CARTODBPOSITRON')
p = figure(x_range = (-2000000, 2000000),
          y_range = (1000000, 7000000),
          x_axis_type = 'mercator',
          y_axis_type = 'mercator')

p.add_tile(tile)

show(p)
```

[image: This is the map that displays]

This is a large dataset, with 2,303,566 entries. I have checked that I have no null values in any of the columns that I am using, as well as verifying the correct data types (lat/lon are `float64`).

Comment: Did you check you browser console for errors, too?

Comment: @mosc9575 Thanks for the edits and suggestion. I went back and restarted the kernel, cleared the output, and ran everything again. The cell ran, and a few seconds afterwards an error did pop up in the browser console: 

```lang.js
Couldn't process kernel message SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.deserialize (serialize.js:63:1)
    at kernel.js:1008:1;
```

Comment: Bokeh prioritize interactive features, but this entailes some trade-offs. Bokeh is not suitable for a scatter plot with 2.3M points, you should look at something like Holoviews+Datashader (which use Bokeh under the hood in a way that can be effective for that many points). As for the immediate question it's impossible to speculate without some of the data to actually use to run and investigate directly. Most likely it is a coordinate transform issue, but that's just speculation. As for the console message, that is coming from Jupyter, not Bokeh, and is probably not related.

Comment: @bigreddot Thanks so much for the information, I just returned to add to this thread. It's definitely an issue with the sheer number of points I'm trying to plot. I did some more experimenting this morning, first trying one of my coordinates by itself and then taking a smaller slice of the dataframe - both of which worked and plotted my points. Thank for your advice!!

Answer (score 1):

Returning to answer my own question here. After doing some more testing based on helpful comments I received from @mosc9575 and @bigreddot, I determined that the size of my dataset is the reason for Bokeh failing to display the map. I used a single point first, and then a small slice of my dataframe - and the map displayed just fine.

I hope this is helpful to someone else at some point!

Thanks to everyone who assisted.